# permission classes IsAuthenticated not working in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-serializer, auth-token

I've used token authentication, and it's working fine i.e. it is authenticating a user and then the user is logged in. But in my views I've set permission classes to IsAuthenticated for one of the views, and it is not allowing to the user even if he is an authenticated user.
Below is the screenshot where it says i'm logged in (jadhav@gmail.com) :

[image]

and the very next tab to this, it says "authentication details not provided":

[image]

Can someone tell what's wrong?
ok, I'm providing details:
these are my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', )
}
```

This is how I authenticated:

class UserLoginAPIView(APIView):

```
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        # new_data = serializer.data
        if serializer.data:
            user = authenticate(username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password'])
            login(request, user)
            print("IsAuthenticated", user.is_authenticated)
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key},
                        status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Another View where I put restrictions:

class BoardCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):

```
queryset = Boards.objects.all()
serializer_class = BoardCreateSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: I don't think the built in api docs allow posts?  I could be wrong.  check the browser dev tools and make sure you're actually sending a post with the token.  That said, you should add more information about how you're adding permission classes and how you're adding the token

Comment: also, the header required for authentication is `Authorization`, so make sure your token is there

Comment: you can use Postman for set authentication on header

Comment: @Jason Edited to provide more info

Comment: @MohammadAli tried to provide more info, may now you can tell where I messed up..

Comment: @user10058776 have you checked my answer below? do you now get a clear picture of the flow?

Comment: @Ken4scholars I checked user password(used django 'authenticate' function), in validate method of my serializer, and now trying to pass that user to my views where token is to be generated. But  I'm facing problem how to catch the values using 'serializer.validated_data[' ']' in my views.

Comment: @user10058776 you don't need to use the django authenticate function. First get the user using the login, then call `user.check_password(password)`. If it returns true then add the user to the `validated_data` which you can access in the view using `serializer.validated_data['user']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @Reza hinted, you're missing the point of token authentication. You're trying to use the basic authentication flow instead. The flow is like this:

1. Client requests a token from the server using login and password
2. Server verifies that your credentials are correct, creates a token and returns it to the client
3. In subsequent requests, client adds the token to the Auth header like this:

   `Authorization: Token <the_client_token>`

So what you should do in your login view is verify the user credentials and create a token. you shouldn't try to perform the authentication yourself. You can rename the view to `obtain_token` so as not to confuse its function.

Check the article @Reza linked for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In django rest framework, You should provide token in your request headers. here is the sample with curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token <MY_TOKEN>" http://my-api-url
```

Also check that in your `settings.py` at least you have these lines:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
}
```

**For more understanding** read this [doc from django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Comment: I tried to give more info..can you please check out

Comment: did you read the article or send it via token header that i Provided? just get token and then send a request to your Url with permission on it with `Authorization: Token <your token>` header set.